# Catch Block Debug Statement not executing after an exception is thrown?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, g++

## Problem

I have a GLSLFailedToLoadException that derives from an exception class GlHelperException.

GlHelperException has the virtual throw function to describe the error with the title property of the exception and the line number with filename.

But when I test the exception in the main function the catch block is not printing the correct what() function debug log and returns terminate called after throwing an instace of GLSLFailtedToLoadException.

### The Exception Definition

```
class GlHelperException: public std::exception{
public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw(){
        return (std::string(this->title) + 
        " - in file " + 
        std::string(this->filename) + 
        " at line " + 
        std::to_string(this->line)).c_str();    
    }

protected:

    const char *title;
    const char *filename;
    int line;
};


class GLSLFailedToLoadException: public GlHelperException{
public:
    GLSLFailedToLoadException(const char *filename, int line);
};


GLSLFailedToLoadException::GLSLFailedToLoadException(const char *filename, int line){
    this->filename = filename;
    this->line = line;
    this->title = "Failed to load and compile GLSL program ";
}
```

### The Test Throw Site

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
/* Irrelevant Code*/

    try{
        throw new GLSLFailedToLoadException(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    }
    catch(GLSLFailedToLoadException &e){
        std::cout<<"Exception Caught"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Actual Results

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'GLSLFailedToLoadException*'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

### Expected Results

```
Failed to load and compile GLSL program in __FILE__ at __LINE__
```

Comment: In your `GLSLFailedToLoadException` constructor you *really* ought to use the initialization list rather than the constructor body. Also then change your `const char *` members to be `const std::string`s so you actually make a copy of the passed in values rather than just storing pointers that are about to become invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are throwing a pointer to an object but trying to catch an object (by reference).

Change your `throw` statement to throw an object:

```
throw GLSLFailedToLoadException(__FILE__, __LINE__);
```

I would also recommend to always `catch` exceptions by `const` reference, so:

```
catch (const GLSLFailedToLoadException& e)
```

As your code is currently written, you fail to catch the exception and it thus leaves `main()`, resulting in the result you see - an uncaught exception terminating the program.

You also need to use `std::string`s in your exception object rather than pointers (`const char *`), because the pointers you currently store do not live for the duration of the object, so you need to make copies of the pointed to strings.

Comment: But now the output is Exception Caught

Comment: The Debug Log is not printing

Comment: GlHelperException has that bit which I am inheriting in the GLSLFailedToLoadException

Comment: @SiddharthSingh : Change `const char *title;` and `const char *filename;` to be `std::string`. You cannot just store those pointers.

Comment: @SiddharthSingh That's a totally different problem that should warrant a different question. However, you create a ***temporary*** `std::string` object, one that is immediately destructed, which means that the pointer you return becomes immediately invalid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understood what you meant but How do I go about solving that? Can you post an answer with the explanation.

Comment: @SiddharthSingh To expand on the problem pointed out by Jesper Juhl, instead of storing the pointers as members in the object, construct the full string in the constructor and store it (as a `std::string` object). Since the string is stored in the object, pointers to it (and its contained raw string) will be valid all throughout the lifetime of the exception object.

Comment: Thanks, Solved it. Stored it in a string generated at construction of the instance :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude will you add the solution as an answer, or should I do it. what is the right way to let the people know the correct solution to my problem? in SOF

Comment: @SiddharthSingh I updated my answer to mention the string issue. And to answer "what is the right way to let the people know the correct solution to my problem? " : You *accept* the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: @SiddharthSingh As I said originally, it should have been posted as a new question, but in this case I'd say you don't have to.